# Как правильно парсить сайт на node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Никогда не сталкивался с парсингом, может кто объяснить как правильно, чтобы поменьше кода и лишних модулей.

Спарсить хотя бы имя и фамилию со своей странички у вк. Уже нашел клас в которой содержиться имя:  `<h2 class="page_name"> тут Фамилия Имя </h2>` .

Пробовал написать в клиенте с помощу jq ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://new.vk.com/tvolex',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            var Uname = $(res.responseText).find('.page_name').text();
            console.log(Uname);
        }
    });
```

но получаю я только ошибку

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://new.vk.com/tvolex. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Я так понял что парсинг должен быть на сервере. Как его реализовать?
Заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что это кросдоменный запрос и ответа вы не увидите. С одного сайта нельзя так просто получить ответ от другого. Да, нужно делать с сервера. nodejs или что-либо другое - это ваш выбор.

Comment: Для парсинга из node.js можно использовать библиотеку jsdom: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/README.md , если нет требований по высокой скорости работы, а то она достаточно медлительна и прожорлива. Но очень удобна в использовании.

Comment: *Я так понял что парсинг должен быть на сервере.* -- вы ж написали, что парсите NodeJS'ом. Выходит, нет? Браузером?

Comment: Ну если очень сильно хочется именно в браузере, можно например поставить https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi и тогда можно кроссдоменить (конечно только со своего компьюче)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А я бы сделал с помощью [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), например так

```
var https = require('https');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

https.get(
    {
        hostname: 'new.vk.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/tvolex',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.94 Safari/537.36'
        }
    },
    function (res) {
        var res_data = "";
        res.charset = 'utf-8';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            var data = iconv.encode(iconv.decode(new Buffer(chunk, 'binary'), 'win1251'), 'utf8');
            res_data += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function (chunk) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(res_data);
            var Uname = $('h2[class="page_name"]').text();
            console.dir(Uname);
        });
    }
).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Got error:" + e.message);
});
```

Comment: Плюсую за Cheerio

Answer (score 1):

Приведенная ошибка говорит о том, что данный запрос является кросдоменным и ответа вы не получите. Нельзя так просто с одного сайта получить контент страницы другого.

А вот с сервера - ради бога. 
Если интересуетесь Node.js - могу предложить использовать очень простую в обращении библиотеку [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/README.md).

Для чего-то серьезного и нагруженного она, вероятно, не подойдет, но если объемы не большие - самое оно. Очень удобна в использовании.

При условии установленного node и загруженной библиотеки, данный простейший код позволяет работать с контентом страницы, как в браузере, даже с использованием jQuery:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env(
    "https://new.vk.com/id1",
    ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
    function (err, window) {
        var $ = window.$;
        console.log("username: ", $(".page_name").text());
        /** username:  Pavel  Durov */
     }
);
```

Сохраняем этот код в файл app.js (к примеру) и запускаем из консоли

```
node ./app.js
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже написал)

Comment: Если человек дружит с JQuery то лучше Сheerio, хотя я не дружил с ним, но относительно быстро разобрался что к чему, и теперь вполне нормально им пользуюсь.